# Post images suddenly blurry

Tags: html, image, blogger, blogspot, blurry

My blogger images suddenly became blurry. Tried to change the src s72 line as suggested but nothing changed. Tried changing templates, but images which were hq are still blurry. Dont know what to do. Site is lemongrasslane.com

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve]. See [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/4642212).

Comment: Problem in CSS code, put it here, please.

Answer (score 0):

You have many JavaScript errors in your template code, try to debug them or add the following to your code before `</body>` tag. This code will replace the parameter `/s72-c/` with `/s600-c/` from all images.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
    var images = document.querySelectorAll('img[src*="/s72-c/"]');
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        images[i].src = images[i].src.replace('/s72-c/','/s600-c/');
    }
    // ]]>
</script>
```